# Two or more ESP32s and Raspberry Pi communication over Bluetooth

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, esp32

I'm a second year college student working on a Bluetooth communication project using Raspberry Pi and ESP32.
After pairing Raspberry Pi and multiple ESP32s, I'm looking for a way for RPi to communicate with 3-4 specific ESP32s simultaneously.
I looked it up with my colleagues, but I could only find a way for RPi to communicate with one ESP32.
There was no way to communicate with two or more ESP32 simultaneously.
Looking for a way for RPi to communicate with two or more ESP32s at the same time.
Can you help me if you know open source that way for RPi to communicate withe two or more ESP32s at the same time?
We want to use the RPi as a server because it should be possible to connect more than one client to it.
Thank you.

What we use is Raspberry Pi 4 model B 4GB and ESP32.

We found this link, but I don't know if this is correct because there is no answer from the questioner.

[Raspberry Pi and ESP32 communication over bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806601/raspberry-pi-and-esp32-communication-over-bluetooth)